# Get array length by pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int narr[4] = {0};
int *pnarr = narr;
printf("size of pnarr:%d and *pnarr:%d\n", sizeof(pnarr), sizeof(*pnarr));
```

The `sizeof(pnarr)` return the pointer type size.
But the `sizeof(*pnarr)` return the int type size.
Why?

Does the `pnarr` point at the first element of `narr`, so I cannot get the array length by `pnarr`?

How can I get the array length by pointer?

Here is the code of get array length by pointer. Is it right?

```
int arr_len(int *arr) {
    int len = 0;
    while (*arr)
    {
        arr++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Comment: You got it. But I think you cannot simply get the array size that easily...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get is actually what is expected to happen. With

```
int *pnarr;
sizeof (pnarr);
```

you get the size of a `int*` pointer, that is an address (usually 4 or 8 bytes depending on your system architecture). You get it whatever address yiu assign to it.

---

The `arr_len ()` function you posted in the question will not find the length of the array, because it wrongly assumes that the last element is 0. That is usually not true.

That is done instead with *strings* (char arrays), which actually are chars terminated by a 0. But in that case it is a standatd, and you are sure that the string won't contain zeros in the middle of it.

---

In conclusion, if you need the total size in bytes of the array, you can get it from the original array name with

```
sizeof(narr)
```

If you need the number of elements of the array, instead, just use

```
sizeof(narr)/sizeof(narr [0])
```

So you can't do it with the pointer but you need the original array "reference".

Comment: `narr` is a pointer, `pnarr` is also a pointer. What's the difference of both.

Comment: @Jaune Because `narr `, for the compiler, is also the name of the array. It is some sort of special pointer. It's not an _lvalue_: you cannot assign to it another address; it will always _reference_ the array, within its scope. `pnarr` is just a pointer. The compiler knows it points to an integer (in this case) but don't knows _how many_ integers there are.. Furthermore it is a valid _lvalue_: you can assign a new value to it.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior.  pnarr is a pointer so sizeof() should return the size of int pointer. Dereferenced pnarr is an int so sizeof() should return the size of int. I suggest you read the documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the *expression* `*pnarr` is `int`, so `sizeof *pnarr == sizeof (int)`.  The type of the expression `narr` is `int [4]`, so `sizeof narr == sizeof (int [4])`.

Under most circumstances, the expression `narr` will be converted (“decay”) from type `int [4]` to type `int *` - the exceptions occur when the expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or when the array is a string literal that’s used to initialize an array of character type in a declaration.

You cannot get the size of the array from a pointer to the first element - you have to keep track of that manually.